# Odoo Module - calling a method of another model

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to call the `wkf_confirm_order` method of the purchase order model.

In my code, I use the line:

**`po.wkf_confirm_order( self, cr, uid, [po.id] )`**

I get the following stack trace, and don't understand the issue with the parameters. Some help would be most appreciated.

```
File "/etc/odoo/addons/asn_import/asn_model.py", line 60, in do_import_file

po.wkf_confirm_order( self, cr, uid, [po.id] )

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 254, in wrapper

return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 580, in new_api

result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
TypeError: wkf_confirm_order takes at most 5 arguments (9 given)
```

The po object was created with the following command (values hardcoded for now):

```
 po = self.env['purchase.order'].create(cr, uid, {'partner_id':name_asc[0],'location_id':12,'pricelist_id':2})
```

Comment: What is the `po` in your method `po.wkf_confirm_order`...??  Means its the object of `purchase.order`..  if it is(`po = self.pool.get('purchase.order')`)... then why you pass `self` in your method... remove it...  And its fine...  :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It is indeed a purchase.order. Unfortunately, the change you suggested gives an error (TypeError: wkf_confirm_order() takes at most 5 arguments (8 given)). I have tried it with just [po.id] as a parameter, and I put a logger in the wkf_confirm_order method, and no value was set for ids. Any thoughts?

Comment: `context` is remaining...  try with Odedra's answer....

Answer (score 0):

self shouldn't be given as a parameter when you call a method.
The only parameters you need are cr, uid, ids (in this case [po.id]) and context (if not provided it will be None)

self will be automatically parsed to the method by Odoo

This code should work:

```
po.wkf_confirm_order(cr, uid, [po.id] )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this gives an error (TypeError: wkf_confirm_order() takes at most 5 arguments (8 given)). I have tried it with just [po.id] as a parameter, and I put a logger in the wkf_confirm_order method, and no value was set for ids. Any thoughts?

Comment: you could try po.id as parameter instead op [po.id]
if this still doesn't work we probably need some more code as example

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `po.id` is a purchase order record id.

Replace your code

```
po.wkf_confirm_order( self, cr, uid, [po.id] )
```

with

```
po.wkf_confirm_order(cr, uid, [po.id], context=context)
```